# Outer API request data storage in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, api, session

I have a Rails 3 app with API to the central app that provide some data.

I've drop an API realization into `lib/` folder and found I can't access session method directly. So the question - how could I access the session from library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that accessing to session from lib or a model is not a good idea. Session information should only be used directly from controllers;

If you need to use session information in a model or within a library, it's a better idea to process the session information in the controller and pass it as parámeters.

There are several reasons behind it (mainly OOD), but a hint to detect the problem could be that testing the object would need to create a session object, and that is not a good practice in TDD.

Comment: Probably you have a point, I just don't like the idea to create one more useless abstract entity in place it isn't really required.